# Object declaration with preceding :: in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

What does following represent in C++?

```
::SomeNameSpace::SomeClass abc;
```

Basically how is this different from

```
SomeNameSpace::SomeClass abc;
```

Comment: It's like the difference between "Paris" and "Paris, France". Same thing, usually, unless you're Texan.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Not really, because `::Paris` by definition cannot be the same as `France::Paris`.

Comment: Well okay it could have been `using`'d....

Comment: When you see this, likely it's because the author typed :: to get code hints.

Comment: @BasinhetVeld: Or they're a good programmer. One of the two.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: `France` was implied!

Comment: @KerrekSB: The standard implies no namespace! Unless the context of the conversation implies it (ADL) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `::` operator is the *scope* operator; it denotes some specific scope. If there is no prefix then it denotes the global scope.

So if `SomeNameSpace` is in the global scope, then `::SomeNameSpace` and `SomeNameSpace` are the same. The difference is if you're in a non-global scope and use `SomeNameSpace`, because then it's first looked for in the current scope.